# Unable to Move File from one location to another location on linux file system using java

Tags: java, apache-commons-io

I am trying to move files from one location to another location in Linux file system. Actually my source directory is on one file system and destination directory is mounted on to the same file system. So am using `File.renameTo()` method of File class to move the files. But it is failing to move the files. But when i use the same logic to move the files from one directory to another directory that are mounted on same file system, it is working fine.. So i am thinking `file.renameTo()` is platform dependent. So am using other classes to move the files. So, Now my choice is to go for `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils` class. It contains method such as,

```
public static void moveFile(File srcFile,File destFile) throws IOException
```

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#moveFile%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File%29

So i downloaded commons-io-1.3 version jar. It contains so many methods to copy file but am unable to find this moveFile method. Please can any one tell me whether i downloaded the correct jar file ?

Can any one please tell me the jar that contains `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.(File srcFile,File destFile)` method.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why would you use commons-io version 1.3 when 2.4 is current?

Answer (score 2):

The javadoc clearly says '1.4'.

```
Since:
1.4
```

So you won't find it in 1.3.

Answer (score 2):

Java 1.7 has a more reliable way of moving files, try it

```
java.nio.file.Files.move(Path source, Path target, CopyOption... options)
```

Comment: Thanks. I downloaded both commons-io.1.3 and commons-io-2.0 versions. But i tried only with 1.3. Now i will try with 2.0 version.

Comment: commons-io-2.0 resolved my problem. Now i am able to move files from one location to another location. But if the destination dir is already contains the file, it is throwing the exception org.apache.commons.io.FileExistsException: File already exists in destination. But i dont want to get this exception. Instead of this i want to overwrite the old file. So i am trying to do this.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

May be helpful for some one

```
Path pathobj1 = Paths.get(srcDir,filename);
Path pathobj2= Paths.get(targetDir,pathobj1.getFileName().toString());
Files.move(pathobj1 , pathobj2, REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Package:

```
import static java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING;
```